# how to retrive record in textbox from mysql table with next and previous button

Tags: php, html, mysql

In my html form there are 4 Text box and 2 buttons `previous` and `next`
I want to display table record in `form.and` when user click `next` button the next record should be fetch in Text box.
please help guys 
thanks in advance

Comment: You may include the code you are working on your post. [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

    $id = 0;  
    if(isset($_POST['next']))
    {

       $id=$id++;
       $que = mysql_query("select * from table where id ='$id'");
       $data = mysql_fetch_array();
       $data1 = $data[1];
       $data1 = $data[2];
       $data1 = $data[3];
       $data1 = $data[4];
    }
    if(isset($_POST['prev']))
    {

       $id=$id--;
       mysql_fetch_array(select * from table where id ='$id')

       $data1 = $data[1];
       $data1 = $data[2];
       $data1 = $data[3];
       $data1 = $data[4];
    }
?>
<form method = "post">
<button name="prev">

<input type="text" value="$data1">
<input type="text" value="$data2">
<input type="text" value="$data3">
<input type="text" value="$data4">
<button name="next">   

</form>
```